# Appearing question mark instead of text only in safari, Using fabricjs - textbox

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, fabricjs

Using Fabric js on canvas, On random events like on load, changing font family/fontsize/fontstyle  appear question mark instead of text. Working fine in all browser except safari and iOS safari.

[image]

Below are the font family list :-

```
$scope.fontFamilies = [
            {name:'Abril Fatface',value:'Abril Fatface',type:'400'},
            {name:'Aldrich',value:'Aldrich',type:'400'},
            {name:'Alex Brush',value:'Alex Brush',type:'400'},
            {name:'Allura',value:'Allura',type:'400'},
            {name:'Balthazar Regular',value:'Balthazar',type:'400'},

            {name:'Crimson Text Regular',value:'Crimson Text',type:'400'},

            {name:'Graduate',value:'Graduate',type:'400'},
            {name:'Gravitas One',value:'Gravitas One',type:'400'},
            {name:'Great Vibes',value:'Great Vibes',type:'400'},
            {name:'Italianno',value:'Italianno',type:'400'},
            {name:'Ledger',value:'Ledger',type:'400'},
            {name:'Limelight',value:'Limelight',type:'400'},
            {name:'Mate SC Regular',value:'Mate SC',type:'400'},
            {name:'Michroma',value:'Michroma',type:'400'},
            {name:'Montserrat Regular',value:'Montserrat',type:'400'},
            {name:'Mr De Haviland Regular',value:'Mr De Haviland',type:'400'},

            {name:'Open Sans Condensed Light',value:'Open Sans Condensed',type:'300'},

            {name:'Open Sans Regular',value:'Open Sans',type:'400'},

            {name:'Oswald',value:'Oswald',type:'400'},

            {name:'Rosarivo',value:'Rosarivo',type:'400'},

            {name:'Stint Ultra Condensed',value:'Stint Ultra Condensed',type:'400'},

            {name:'Syncopate Regular',value:'Syncopate',type:'400'},
            {name:'Vast Shadow',value:'Vast Shadow',type:'400'}

        ];
```

Some code and flow below :
Creating object

```
  var canvas = this.__canvas  =  new fabric.Canvas('canvasArea',
                    {selection:false,
                    allowTouchScrolling:true,
                    preserveObjectStacking: true});
```

Then load canvas from json

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(res.data.templateJson, function() {
..
}
```

below is change font family function

```
 $scope.updateFontFamily = function (family) {
            console.log(family);
            var tempFontFamily = {};
            for(var loop=0;loop<$scope.fontFamilies.length;loop++) {
                if(family==$scope.fontFamilies[loop].name){
                    tempFontFamily.type = $scope.fontFamilies[loop].type;
                    tempFontFamily.value = $scope.fontFamilies[loop].value;
                }
            }
            var tObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
            tObj.setFontFamily(tempFontFamily.value);
            tObj.setFontStyle(tempFontFamily.type);
            var text = tObj.getText();
            tObj.setText("");
            tObj.setText(text);
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
```

Importing all font family in the index file

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alex+Brush');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Balthazar');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,400i,600');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Goudy+Bookletter+1911');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Graduate');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gravitas+One');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Italianno');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ledger');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Limelight');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mate+SC');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+De+Haviland');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i,700');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,800');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosarivo:400,400i');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Stint+Ultra+Condensed');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Syncopate:400,700');
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vast+Shadow');
```

Comment: always use a "generic family" fallback like serif or sans-serif etc clearly your safari doesn't have any of those fonts - are you loading fonts in the page? (i.e. using @font css stuff) perhaps you're using a format that safari doesn't understand - like `WOFF2` for example ... only safari and internet exploder can't use that

Comment: Yes I am loading all the fonts which I am using and most of the time appears properly but frequently changing the font family or any random event question mark appear.

Comment: oh, right - sorry, didn't read the question very well - safari, the new internet exploder - the problem with "random events" that are truly "random" and cause intermittent issues is, it's almost damn near impossible to debug without some code

Comment: I am sharing flow and functions, hope that helps to debug it

Comment: @JaromandaX please have a glance at the code I shared.

Comment: so this is the font family in canvas? sorry, above my head

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152048/discussion-between-neeraj-rathod-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: You should show HOW are you loading the font. That may be the problem.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, I am using canvas fabricjs, and showing a list of font family in a drop down, calling the function updateFontFamily, while selecting any font family. I've shared my code please have a look

Comment: That is fine, you are NOT LOADING any font. You need to load a font and wait for completition.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi please have a look, I have edited my post and add impot code in it